# IIS 7.5 - Exposing a website on a different port is not visible outside of localhost

Tags: .net, iis, dns

I have a Windows 2008 Web Server with IIS 7.5. There is a website on port 80 which I can hit using the IP address or domain name. I added another website on port 83, and if I navigate to localhost:83 on the server I can see the website just fine. But when trying to access the website using the IP address and port number I am getting a 404.

I have a feeling that I will need a DNS entry or some other settings to expose this site to the internets.

To reiterate:

- http://72.xxx.xxx/     resolves fine (port 80)
- http://72.xxx.xxx:80/  resolves fine (port 80)
- http://72.xxx.xxx:83/  **does not resolve**
- localhost/      resolves fine (port 80)
- localhost:80    resolves fine
- localhost:83    resolves fine (on the server only)

Obviously my binding is set to HTTP *83 with all IP address, same as the one on port 80

My end game is to make this a sub domain, which I know requires DNS, but I am hoping to just expose it using the port for now.

Any advice would be most appreciated.

Comment: What is your network structure like? Make sure your router is forwarding port 83 to the server.

Comment: This is a host dedicated server in the cloud. Its a Win 2K8 Server with full root (admin) access. I control DNS but I don't believe I have access to the router. Good point though. It could be impossible because of the topology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution - I had to add a INBOUND rule to allow port 81 through the firewall. This is why I am a developer and not a system admin, though these days the line blurs.

Thanks for taking a look guys.